# Magento 2 - Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Cannot instantiate interface

Tags: magento2.3, error, export

When i try to export the products from magento admin panel i got this error

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Cannot instantiate interface Magento\Framework\MessageQueue\ConfigInterface in 
/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php:121 Stack trace: #0 
/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Compiled.php(108): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->createObject('Magento\\Framewo...', Array) #1 
/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Compiled.php(150): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Compiled->create('Magento\\Framewo...') #2 
/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Compiled.php(79): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Compiled->get('Magento\\Framewo...') #3 
/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php(70): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Compiled->create('Magento\\Framewo...') #4 
/vendor/magen in /vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php on line 121
```

Answer (score 1):

I've faced this issue too after upgrading from Magento 2.2.11 to to 2.3.6. It turns out that between those two versions, Magento have released a lot of new "modules" to work alongside other areas of the Admin, and one of them is "Magento_MessageQueue". This, according to Magento, "provides support of Advanced Message Queuing Protocol", and is used by the export module to provide the ability to generate the file in the background, and then let you know when it's ready to download.

This module was not enabled by default, so in terminal I had to do the following:

```
php bin/magento module:enable Magento_MessageQueue
```

After upgrading and compiling the code, the product export worked as described above.

For this to work, the Magento cron must be properly set-up. However if this doesn't work, you can force this to be processed via another terminal command:

```
php bin/magento queue:consumers:start exportProcessor
```

Comment: I enabled Magento_Amqp and threw "PHP Fatal error" during setup:upgrade until I ran enable Magento_MessageQueue.

Answer (score 0):

Please run the below command

**php bin/magento setup:upgrade**

**php bin/magento setup:di:compile**

Then check again

Comment: I run that but now the site is down: There has been an error processing your request
Unable to retrieve deployment version of static files from the file system.

Comment: https://magento.farmagsa.com.ar/ into the front and into the backend too

Comment: Please run this

php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f

Comment: Done, but i got the same error again

Comment: Do the same proccess after do this rm -rf generated

rm -rf var/*

Comment: This page contains the following errors:
error on line 2 at column 1: Extra content at the end of the document
Below is a rendering of the page up to the first error.

Comment: What is the exact error message?

Comment: My message, the exact error: This page contains the following errors:
error on line 2 at column 1: Extra content at the end of the document
Below is a rendering of the page up to the first error.